# Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Estou conectando no banco de dados e chamando uma `procedure` para inserir no banco mas ocorre esse erro vocês sabem o motivo:

**Código:**

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

con = Nothing
cmd = Nothing

Try

    con.ConnectionString = "Server = ;Database=;User Id=;Password = ;"

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd = New SqlCommand("prdInserirRegistro", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@dtLog", SqlDbType.DateTime))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@dsLog", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000))

    'recebe o parâmetro selecionado na combobox
    cmd.Parameters("@dtLog").Value = Now
    cmd.Parameters("@dsLog").Value = txtBoxLog.Text


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("erro em: " & ex.Message)
Finally

    If Not con Is Nothing Then
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End If
    con = Nothing

    If Not cmd Is Nothing Then
        cmd.Dispose()
    End If
    cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Qual erro acontece?

Comment: Em que linha dá o erro? Onde estão declaradas as variáveis `con`, `conecta`, `comando`, `cmd`? Nomes bons pra causar confusão.

Comment: este é o erro  :que ocorre Object reference not set to an instance of an object as variaveis estao declaradas acima estao assim:
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()


        con = Nothing
        cmd = Nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está nessa ordem:

1. `Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()`
2. `cmd = Nothing`
3. `cmd.Connection = con`

---

1. `Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()`
2. `con = Nothing`
3. `con.ConnectionString = "Server = ;Database=;User Id=;Password = ;"`

---

No segundo passo você atribui `con` e `cmd` a `Nothing`.

Logo, as referências que eles tinham das instâncias das classes criadas no passo 1 são perdidas.

Remova os trechos do item 2 (`con = Nothing` e `cmd = Nothing`)

Comment: obrigado , funcionou

Comment: Legal! Fico feliz por ter ajudado. Atualizei a resposta explicando um pouco melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Tem que tirar esse `con = Nothing`. Na verdade o código está bem confuso, fazendo coisas sem sentido, pode ser que resolvendo este erro encontre outros.

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection() //criou o objeto
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
con = Nothing // ===============================>abandonou objeto
cmd = Nothing
Try
    'Aqui tenta acessar o objeto que não existe, por isso dá esse erro
    con.ConnectionString = "Server = ;Database=;User Id=;Password = ;"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/SqlConnection.vb).